# android popup window with webpage in it

Tags: android

how to create an android popup window with webpage in it.

Answer (score 2):

you could create a new activity which is displayed as dialog `<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">` and put a WebView in it

Comment: hi martin
  how can i display android activity as dialog

Comment: just add the following theme-entry to your activity description in the androidmanifest.xml file:

<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">